# конфигурация EF many-to-many с ключом типа string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть два класса с зависимостью many-to-many.

```
public class EquipmentTemplate 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string StringId { get; set; }
    // other properties...
    MaterialTemplate MaterialTemplates { get; set; }
    ICollection<MaterialTemplate> Materials { get; set; }
}

    public class MaterialTemplate 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string StringId { get; set; }
    // other properties...
    EquipmentTemplate EquipmentTemplates { get; set; }
    ICollection<EquipmentTemplate> Equipments { get; set; }
}
```

Нужно сделать чтобы эти классы, в базе данных в производной таблице, ссылались друг на друга не по ID, а по StringId, при том что StringId не является ключом в классе.

Пробовал через FluentApi так:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<MaterialTemplate>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Equipments)
            .WithRequired(e => e.MaterialTemplates)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.StringId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EquipmentTemplate>()
                    .HasMany(e => e.Materials)
                    .WithRequired(e => e.EquipmentTemplates)
                    .HasForeignKey(e => e.StringId)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

но ругается что типы ключей не совпадают:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   MaterialTemplate_Materials_Source_MaterialTemplate_Equipments_Target:
>   : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential
>   constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the
>   Principal Role. The type of property 'StringId' on entity
>   'EquipmentTemplate' does not match the type of property 'Id' on entity
>   'MaterialTemplate' in the referential constraint
>   'MaterialTemplate_Equipments'.

Comment: А какой резон делать в качестве ключей строчные значения? Может стоит пересмотреть этот момент, а не создавать проблему, а потом пытаться ее решить?

Comment: Я уже пересмотрел, варианты есть, но если есть решение по моему вопросу то это было бы лучше всего. Конечно если больше проблем чем плюсов то никто такое решение не возьмется использовать.